# qgis: can't find eclipse pydev path using remote debugger in linux enviroment

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm trying to configure pydev and eclipse with qgis for remote debug. Everything worked fine in eclipse and i can start the debug server.
 The problem is that Remote debugger plugin requires a pydev path and i can't find it anywhere in a linux enviroment.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus), Qgis 2.18, eclipse photon and python 2.7.

[image: pydevd path form]